# How to view a file in a new window in TextMate?

Tags: textmate, new-window

I am giving TextMate a try for some quick editing of a few script files. I would like to be able to view two files side by side while working on them instead of having to switch between tabs. I can't figure out how to display a file in a new window.

I tried dragging the tab off the window (tear off), looking through the menu options, and a quick Google search, but didn't find anything. I ran across [a suggestion for this feature](http://wiki.macromates.com/Suggestions/OpenInNewWindow) from 2005 which isn't encouraging.

I feel like I must be missing something. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: sounds like a question for superuser.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I posted a bit too soon. Right click on the tab of the file you want to open, and there is an option to "move it to a new window".